# how to rotate object according to the rotation of the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

i want to rotate player body according to the rotation of the camera. like FPS game.

**STEPS >>**

1. When the camera is facing down, i can see my body under the camera.
2. My body has to follow the location of the camera.
3. My body has to also follow the rotation of the camera.
4. So i can see my body anywhere when i facing down camera.

here is my code. It is attached to body(the object i have to rotate).

```
 private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = arCamera.transform.position;
        transform.rotation = arCamera.transform.rotation;
    }
```

I want to see my body when the camera facing down but body rotates according with camera so i never see the body. How can i see it? ;(
Please help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Traditionally, FPS doesn't render the player's body at all (for the player), although they usually provide some sort of drop shadow. (Star Citizen being one of the more famous exceptions to this)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're wanting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want your body only copy the rotation around the Y axis.

It is way easier to calculate with vectors than with quaternion rotations ;)

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.position = arCamera.transform.position;

    // Take your camera forward vector
    var camForward = arCamera.transform.forward;
    // erase the Y component
    camForward.y = 0;
    // and now make your body look into this flattened direction
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookDirection(camForward, Vector3.up);
}
```

See also [`Quaternion.LookDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html).

This has of course one little flaw: The moment the camera looks up or down more than 90° the body is flipping to the opposite direction. So you either want to limit the camera rotation or come up with a different approach.

E.g. assuming that it is way harder for a human being to rotate (tilt) the head more then 90° on the `Z` axis, you could instead also do

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.position = arCamera.transform.position;

    // Take your camera forward vector
    var camRight = arCamera.transform.right;
    // erase the Y component
    camRight.y = 0;
    // and now align the body's right axis with this flattened direction
    // Since we never touch the object's up vector this works without problems
    transform.right = camRight;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply!
But this is not the result I want... 
When i rotate any axis, the body rotates strangely.
I want the body to follow the position and rotation value of the camera. Your code rotates well on the Y-axis, but if you rotate on a different axis, you get a strange result...
The body should always move as attached to the bottom of the camera. So, even if the camera exceeds 90 degrees, i can always see the front of the body.

I don't know if I explained it well... ;(
Have a nice day!